# If a random variable $X$ is integrable, how do we show that $X^2$ is also integrable?

Tags: probability

If we know that a random variable $X$ is integrable, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(|X|) < \infty$, how do we show that $X^2$ is also integrable?

Comment: Maybe try $X(\omega) = {1 \over \sqrt{\omega}}$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: It's not always true.

Comment: As was already noted, this is false. Also, I'll add that it isn't exactly correct to write that $X$ being integrable means $\mathbb{E}[X]<\infty$, because the expectation might also be $-\infty$, or it might not exist at all. $X$ being integrable means $\mathbb{E}(|X|)<\infty$. (which is equivalent to "$\mathbb{E}[X]$ exists and finite")

Comment: What is the context for this? Did you see this somewhere? Or is it just a  wild guess?

Comment: @Alex the integral is one,not infinity.

Comment: @Alex: $\int_0^1 {1 \over \sqrt{x}} dx = 2$. $\int_0^1 ({1 \over \sqrt{x}} )^2dx = \infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the claim isn't true. For example, we can consider a random variable $X$ with probability density function
$$f_X(x):=\frac{3}{2x^{5/2}}\enspace \text{for }x\in [1,\infty).$$
Then you can verify that
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_{[1,\infty)}xf_X(x)=3<\infty$$
while
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\int_{[1,\infty)}x^2f_X(x)=\infty.$$